# Beacon UUID vs BeaconLayout

Tags: uuid, beacon

I am currently interested on how Beacons are working but I have some questions about it.
For iOS, I only see source code about Beacon UUID. But for Android, I only see "beacon layouts".

Are they the same? Can they be converted from one format to another?

Let's say I have this Beacon UUID:

`636f3f8f-6491-4bee-95f7-d8cc64a863b5`

Is this possible to get the beacon layout? But more specifically, what's a beacon layout exactly?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**A beacon "layout" refers to the beacon format, specifically how the different fields are encoded into bytes needed to transmit the information inside Bluetooth LE advertising packets.**

Some companies like Apple maintain their beacon formats as trade secrets, so they don't allow them to be published.  Open source modules like the Android Beacon Library can't include ways to decode these beacons without publishing them.  So they use a layout string, which is a way for a user to quickly and easily tell the library to decode that beacon.

Here's an example for the open-source AltBeacon format, which doesn't mind folks publishing it:

```
m:2-3=beac,i:4-19,i:20-21,i:22-23,p:24-24,d:25-25
```

This means that a bluetooth LE beacon transmission matching this layout can be encoded/decoded like this:

- Uses a manufacturer advertisement packet (m) with a two byte type code of 0xbeac in byte positions 2 and 3.
- Has its first identifier (ID1 equivalent to iBeacon UUID) in bytes 4-19.
- Has its second identifier (ID2 equivalent to iBeacon major) in bytes 20-21.
- Has its third identifier (ID3 equivalent to iBeacon minor) in bytes 22-23.
- The "p" and "d" parts of the layout refer to a "power" calibration value for distance estimates and a "data" field to store battery level and other manufacturer-specific information.

**There are several other popular beacon formats like iBeacon and Eddystone.**  They have their own layout strings, which are both very similar to the one shown above.

While **you can't use different beacon formats interchangeably**, you can use all these beacon formats on both iOS and Android.  Using a proprietary format on Android is just a matter of doing a Google search to find the right layout string for the beacon format, then configuring it like this:

```
 BeaconManager.getBeaconParsers().add(
   new BeaconParser().setBeaconLayout("<paste layout string here>"));
```

Comment: That's the kind of reply I was totally looking for! Thanks a lot David! Are you aware of any book for me to learn more about beacons (and rights about it)? Thanks again.

Comment: (oooh, aren't you THE David Young, Chief Engineer at Radius Network ? :D )

Comment: I only know of one beacon book [here](https://www.amazon.com/Beacon-Technologies-Hitchhikers-Guide-Beacosystem/dp/1484218884) written by my colleague Steven Statler.  I contributed the chapter on AltBeacon, although the royalty checks have yet to pay for the first beer. :)

Comment: Yes, I just saw you contributed to this book! Thanks a lot. Awesome book!

Comment: hey @davidgyoung
You said that apple keeps its beacon formats as trade secrets.

How is it possible for an Android developer to detect such beacon formats?
I saw a few questions on Stackoverflow that mentioned the iBeacon layout, and it worked with your example "setBeaconLayout("APPLE LAYOUT HERE")" in my Android app to detect iBeacons.

But if I were to "figure" out the layout myself, how I do that?
Isn't copying the layout from other people an infringement to apple trade-secret?

Comment: It's possible because I spent a day with a bluetooth packet sniffer reverse engineering the packets coming out of an iBeacon until I understood how they worked.  The layout is now publicly available and is very simple, perhaps "obvious" given a bit of time observing it, and possibly too simple to use legal means to try to prevent others from using it.  That, however, is a legal question that I do not have the expertise to say definitively.  I doubt copying somebody else's published beacon  layout vs. reverse engineering it yourself makes any legal difference.  But, hey, I'm no lawyer.